# Async Function Brainstorming - Babel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, babeljs

Hey this is more of brainstorming help I think, so sorry if it offends the rules. Just not sure where to ask this.

**Backstory**
I'm working with React, and using Babel to transpile ES6/7. What I'm trying to do is have a component (another class) call a function to notify the application state it needs to change. I want this function call to return immediately instead of blocking on all the following logic.

**Ideas So Far**

1) I'm aware of Promises but I feel like it will make the call too bulky to write. Considering the action taking place outside will not return anything (pure) and won't throw errors that the calling class needs to be aware of (fails gracefully). As I know it I would then have to do this to call this *dispatch* function...

`OtherClass.dispatch()
   .then(() => {})
   .catch(console.error)`

But that seems like boilerplate for no reason.

2) There's the `async` function decorator(?) but I'm under the impression that those require a promise to be returned for resolution with the `await` keyword. Which still sounds like blocking to me, or using the promise `then` pattern

4) I've thought of a mixture, such that the calling function just issues the `dispatch` function and that called function would then execute the `Promise`. If I have it right, the operation should seemingly skip over the promise and return, while the promise will then fire asynchronously, but I'm not sure if this is the case, or best route.

```
function dispatch( ) {  
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
      ...  
   }).then(() => {})  
     .catch(console.error)  
}  

dispatch();
```

5) An older school method of using a queue type array and an infinite polling loop. Calling `dispatch` just pushes the request to the end of the queue, and the loop (maybe using `requestAnimationFrame()`) polls the array and complete's them in order. I'm worried that this might kill cpu/battery in fragile cases, like porting this to React Native where it'll run on a mobile device.

I should note that speed is key. And #5 has a good methodology since it keeps the changes in order, but that feels weird.

Comment: Software Engineering Exchange would be a better place to post this. I see this being downvoted/removed very soon. Might want to change the title and make it more specfic

Comment: @SethWhite really!? That might actually be a good way then. But I've seen sometimes that promises tend to catch ANY errors regardless of where called and then I get unresolved exception errors.

Comment: @CP510 sure, just, try this in your console: `let thing = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {console.log('asdf');resolve(77)});` the console.log will always output, and you can optionally invoke .then() to get the resolution. There's not much point to a returning a promise if you never use it, but it is possible.

Comment: @bholagabbar when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Promise` version can be much simpler:

```
function dispatch() {
    Promise.resolve().then(doTheRealWork);
}
```

That will be async; will never reject unless `doTheRealWork` rejects/throws (and you've said it won't), so no `catch` necessary; etc. It will call `doTheRealWork` async, as soon as possible after scheduled (on most browsers, as a microtask after the current macrotask completes).

You could, of course, give yourself an even more concise utility method:

```
const later = callback => Promise.resolve().then(callback);
```

and

```
function dispatch() {
    later(doTheRealWork);
}
```

Example:

```js
const later = callback => Promise.resolve().then(callback);

function dispatch() {
    later(doTheRealWork);
}

function doTheRealWork() {
    console.log("Doing the real work");
}

console.log("Calling dispatch");
dispatch();
console.log("Back from dispatch");
```

Comment: Awesome I'll try this out! Thanks for the suggestion, was unaware of this pattern

Answer (score 0):

After suggestions from comments I did a quick bit of testing. And was actually surprised at the answer, which is why I'm sharing it if anyone cares or stumbles upon this.

**Test Setup**

I am using react, so I've just generated a view with 1000 simple components (random colored squares) all listening for updates via a callback which changes their color. During the `processAction()` function. `performance.now()` is used to track the timestamps from start of process to end of process (all component's callbacks have been called). A button fires off the `dispatchAction()` function to start the process

**Methods**

I'm abreviating the button press since it just calls `dispatchAction()`; and `processAction()` cause it just loops through an array and randomizes it and calls the callbacks it has registered, so no code in their has been changed in this process.

1) The original blocking method

```
function dispatchAction() {
    this.processAction(); //This used to be all in dispatchAction but I moved it for tests
}
```

Resulting performance: **5-7ms** average

2) T.J. Crowder's suggestion

```
function dispatchAction() {
   Promise.resolve().then(() => this.processAction()) //Used the anon-call because I may use parameters
}
```

Resulting performance: **80-110ms** average (why?)

3) Seth White's suggestion (from comment)

```
function dispatchAction() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.processAction()
      resolve()
   }
}
```

Resulting performance: **4-7ms** average

So #3 returning a promise and not doing anything about the `then` or `catch` actually worked brilliantly. Remained Async, and at least kept the performance reports down to the original.